# Percentage graph when metric contains tags in grafana

Tags: grafana, promql

I am trying to create a graph showing stacked percentage distribution over time for one metric with tags. The metric is counter with different tags. Example:

```
fruits_total{fruit=["apple","banana",...]
```

I am trying to visualise the distribution over time in percentage for fruits, compared to total count.

I tried this query(not working):

```
100*(sum(rate(fruits_total)[1m]) by (fruit)) / sum(rate(fruits_total)[1m])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do the query!
https://promlabs.com/products

For the example it will looks like:

```
100*(sum by (fruit) (rate(fruits_total)[1m]) / on() group_left sum(rate(fruits_total)[1m])
```